# Book for self-teaching invariant measures

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to investigate the expectation value of a quantum Hamiltonian where one of the parameters of the quantum evolution is a 1-D chaotic map. I don't have any formal training on dynamical systems. After reading couple of papers, my intuition is that the invariant measure of a chaotic map should be my starting point to self-teach the concept and eventually proceed to investigate the problem in hand. Now I am looking for a text/reference to study invariant measure of simple logistic/kent maps. Would it be reasonable to buy any or both of the following books? Or does anyone have any other suggestion?

1. Lasota, Andrzej, and Michael C. Mackey. Chaos, fractals, and noise: stochastic aspects of dynamics. Vol. 97. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.
2. Boyarsky, Abraham, and Pawel Gora, eds. Laws of chaos: invariant measures and dynamical systems in one dimension. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Thanks in advance.